# I want to swipe till an element that is present down in the view(iOS)

Tags: java, selenium, appium

Hi I want to swipe to an element that is present down in the screen and that is only accessible after scrolling. 
I have tried the following code.

```
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("direction", "down");
        params.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) driver.findElement(By.name("Hazard"))).getId());
        js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", params);
```

Previously I am able to scroll but not to a particular element. Rather then it just make a predefined scroll by eleminating

```
params.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) driver.findElement(By.name("Hazard"))).getId());
```

. 
But I want it scroll to a specific element.

I am using

```
appium version: 1.15.1
java-client: 7.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text(\"WebView\"));").click();
```

Comment: This is for android. I'm asking for iOS.

Comment: @SammarAhmad : Only Android

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `swipe` operation, you should use `scroll` operation.

You can use it like:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("direction", "down");
params.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) driver.findElement(By.name("Hazard"))).getId());
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", params);
```

Comment: Its not working sir. It is throwing NoSuchElementException.